# Use Steamworks API to pull competitive game scores?

Tags: php, steam-web-api

I have a dilemma that I need to figure out.

So I am building a website, where people can go watch a competitive game (Such as Counter Strike: Global Offensive), perhaps using either a Twitch TV stream, or actually through the matchmaking streaming services that the game may offer (In the case of this example, CS: GO TV).  While playing, members can place "bets" on which teams will win, using some form of credits with no real value.  Of course, the issue here, is that the site will need to be able to pull the score from the game, and update in real time.  So sticking with the example of CS:GO, is there a portion of the Steamworks API, that would allow for real-time pulling of a game's score, through some kind of PHP or JavaScript method?

Comment: Have you tried to ask steam if they provide such api?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to tell you that you can't, for now.

In the API description of the CS:GO Competitive Match Information says:

> It would be interesting to be able to find out competitive match information -- exactly like what DOTA 2 has. It could contain all the players in the map, with their steamids and competitive ranks, the score at half time/full time. There are probably a few more bits of info that could also be included. Pigophone2 16:54, 14 September 2013 (PDT)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, **there is no Steam developed API that does this.**

However many websites still do exactly what you are looking for.

My guess is that they use a regularly updated script which parses websites like ESEA and ESL and pull data about those matches. After all, they are the ones who host almost all big games that people care about.

You'll need to keep up-to-date with private leagues though, as they don't typically publish live stats in an easily parse-able format. GOSU Gamers can help you track any new players that come to the big-league table.